# Flutter JSON parse. Can't display more than one field value

Tags: json, flutter, dart, widget, future

In my code I parse Json Album file. So I have values for 'contentIntro' and 'title'. But i can display only one of them with this code. My target is to display title and contentIntro underneath.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyTitle'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
          future: futureAlbum,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(snapshot.data!.contentIntro),
                //child: Text(snapshot.data!.Title),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Column instead:

```
Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
Text(snapshot.data!.contentIntro),
Text(snapshot.data!.Title),
]
);
```